# A rotated square panel in Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I wonder if it is possible to implement a GUI panel (possibly JPanel) that is of square shape but rotated 90 degrees. Obviously, there will be a top-level container which contains this panel, and visually the main panel is this rotated square panel within.

More specifically, I would divide a panel (called 'A') into 4 equal square sub-panels, and fill these sub-panels with JLabels, for which I am thinking to use GridLayout. And lastly, I would rotate 'A' 90 degrees to give what I want.

From my reading of other similar questions, it seems that you cannot rotate JPanel itself, but you can rotate what is contained within. Is this applicable to my case here? Would appreciate if someone could point out. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The critical thing seems to be painting the components *after* rotating the graphics context. Here's an example:

[image]

Addendum 1:As @Atreys comments, the rotated components are drawn, but interact poorly. If the components must remain usable, event coordinates should also be transformed. Compare this (considerably) more complex [example](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.java.help/msg/d39d5ec36671c22d) that *mirrors* components.

Addendum 2: If you also need to transform the mouse coordinates, this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244157/reverse-java-graphics2d-scaled-and-rotated-coordinates/2244285#2244285) may be helpful.

Addendum 3: Alternatively, consider the `drawString()` examples examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6238908/230513).

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333464 */
public class RotatePanel extends JPanel {

    public RotatePanel() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320, 240));
        this.add(new JLabel("Hello World!", JLabel.CENTER));
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        int w2 = getWidth() / 2;
        int h2 = getHeight() / 2;
        g2d.rotate(-Math.PI / 2, w2, h2);
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("RotatePanel");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new RotatePanel().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: neat trick :)  I was curious how it handled objects you can click, so added a button to the label as well.  It drew it rotated, but also non-rotated (sometimes).  Also, the panel perceives any events registered to it in its non-rotated orientation

Comment: @Atreys: Good point, although a solution is non-trivial. I've elaborated above.

Comment: This is nice, but is this method general? For example, if I only rotate the 'A' panel for 45 degrees, would this make it appear as a diamond shape and everything within rotate 45 degrees as well (e.g. labels, sub-panels edges, etc)? thanks.

Comment: The rotation of the rendering is quite general, as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405799/how-to-rotate-an-image-gradually-in-swing/3420651#3420651); but the components are no longer interactive. It's much like printing in landscape orientation, which is fine for labels. See also this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238037/how-do-i-align-this-text-correctly/6238908#6238908).

Comment: @trashgod Will this work proper when multiple components are in the panel?

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar: I've never tried; while illustrative, I would avoid this approach as a design strategy.

Comment: Except now you need to translate the mouse events and the sizing hints as well ;)

Comment: @trashgod Or just use J(X)Layer, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22976226/is-there-any-way-i-can-rotate-this-90-degrees/22976755#22976755) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25252127/java-rotating-non-square-jpanel-component/25253453#25253453) ... but I'm lazy - pretty example though

Answer (score 3):

Check out [JXTransformer](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/alexfromsun/archive/2006/07/jxtransformer_t.html) in the [SwingHelper](http://java.net/projects/swinghelper/) project over at java.net. This class acts as a component decorator that allows you to apply an arbitrary affine transform to a component.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you would have to have the top-level container (JPanel or other container) be the item that rotates the contents. Really you aren't rotating the items, you are rotating to the painting of the items.

Answer (score 2):

If all you need to do is rotate the text on a JLabel you could use a [Rotated Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/rotated-icon), then you don't have to worry about rotating the panel.