# How to make a rotated panel in java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, rotation

I want to know if there is some way to rotate a panel without changing its shape. I mean I am able to rotate the drawings inside the panel using `rotate()` given in `graphics2D` but the rectangular drawings become diamond shaped. Is there some soln for it?? I mean can I avoid the drawing from becoming diamond shape. The problem is more evident when u change the resolution of the screen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to rotate an image gradually in Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405799/how-to-rotate-an-image-gradually-in-swing)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, rotate the image around its center, as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405799/how-to-rotate-an-image-gradually-in-swing/3420651#3420651).

Comment: but that doesnot seem to help me.. How does first translating and then rotating prevent the rectangular panel from getting deformed. It has to be worked on the resolution.. But I donno how..

Comment: @trashgod how can we  rotate the JPanel control around an angle periodically ?

Comment: @JAVA: As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6333464/230513), you can rotate the graphics context, but rotated components are require some additional effort.