# Rotating a JTextField vertically

Tags: java, swing, rotation, jtextfield

I've seen a number of questions that ask how to rotate a JLabel or image at an arbitrary angle. All I need to do is rotate my text field 90 degrees, but I haven't found an easier way specifically for that angle. I thought I copied the answers correctly, but my text field is not rotating.

Here's an SSCCE of what I'm doing:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class VerticalRotationSSCCE {

private static class VerticalTextField extends JTextField {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public VerticalTextField(String text) {
        super(text);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        int cx = getWidth() / 2;
        int cy = getHeight() / 2;
        g2.rotate(1/2 * Math.PI, cx, cy);
        super.paintComponent(g2);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.getContentPane().add(new VerticalTextField("Foo"));
            frame.pack();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

    });
}

}
```

What am I missing from the answers on how to rotate components?

Comment: check out this link. it rotates it 45 degrees but i'm sure you can amend it to your needs http://www.coderanch.com/t/338773/GUI/java/rotate-text

Comment: the post by Craig Wood is the one to look at..

Comment: I have already seen that page. I can't understand what part Wood is doing differently from mine that makes it able to rotate. Can I please get an explanation of what I'm missing?

Comment: there seems to be a lot he's doing differently! have you tried the last suggestion - the  Graphics2D.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getRotateInstance(theta))?

Comment: AlphaComposite.getRotateInstance does not seem to exist. I am using Java 6. Is it new?

Comment: it was in java 2 maybe it's redundant now

Comment: no i checked it's in java 6

Comment: import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.DisplayMode;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Window;

Comment: @RachelGallen & David Weitzman may have meant `AffineTransform`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't usefully rotate *interactive* components without also transforming the mouse coordinates, but you *can* rotate the graphics context to render *non*-interactive components like `JLabel`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6333584/230513).

In your example, `1/2 * Math.PI != Math.PI / 2`.

[image]

Comment: NB: `1/2` evaluates to zero, so `1/2 * Math.PI` also evaluates to zero.

Comment: I feel really dumb. Haven't coded in about 6 months, so forgetting silly things like integer division. Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 5):

Actually, yes, it can be done, but will require some additional libraries and access to some source code which has vanished off the net.

Using `JXLayer`, it is possible to transform live components at runtime...

[image]

```
public class JLayerTransform {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JLayerTransform();
    }

    public JLayerTransform() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new ExamplePane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ExamplePane extends JPanel {

        private JSlider slider;
        private FieldPane fieldPane;
        private DefaultTransformModel transformModel;

        public ExamplePane() {

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            slider = new JSlider(0, 360);
            slider.setValue(0);
            slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {

                    transformModel.setRotation(Math.toRadians(slider.getValue()));

                }
            });

            fieldPane = new FieldPane();

            transformModel = new DefaultTransformModel();
            transformModel.setRotation(Math.toRadians(0));
            transformModel.setScaleToPreferredSize(true);
            JXLayer<JComponent> rotatePane = TransformUtils.createTransformJXLayer(fieldPane, transformModel);

            add(slider, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            add(rotatePane);

        }
    }

    public class FieldPane extends JPanel {

        public FieldPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
            field.setText("Hello world");

            add(field);

        }
    }
}
```

**Caveats**

This requires [JXLayer](http://java.net/projects/jxlayer/) (I was using version 3), [SwingX](http://swingx.java.net/) (I was using version 1.6.4) and Piet Blok's excellent examples, which no longer seem to be available on the net...

I've put all the source code of JXLayer (version 3) and Piet's examples into a single [zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/re1hmvypp19oqy1/JXLayer-PBJar-Demo.zip) and I would suggest, if you are interested, you grab a copy and store it some where safe.

Comment: There is also a JLayer in the JDK since (1.7) which does basically the same

Comment: @Stephan I've not looked at `JLayer`, I believe there are minor differences, but Piet's API, nothing beats that, which is the main reason I stick with `JXLayer` for the time been (until I have time to reimplement it)