# Rotating the JTextArea using mouse in java

Tags: java, swing, rotation, jtextarea

I recently worked on the MS PowerPoint 2007 and I got interested in rotation option of the text in the presentation Window .

Now  I have created a JTextArea with some text in it.

Now what I want is I want to rotate the JTextArea by mouse (similar in MS PowerPoint 2007)

But I got no Idea of how to start .

Thanks in advance

Comment: write what have you tried and where you are facing problem exactly.

Comment: @Rais Alam I want to know  how to rotate the JTextarea in the mouse direction how to do that

Comment: It's not that it isn't possible, it's just hard to find the right example.  Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324460/rotating-a-jtextfield-vertically/14328881#14328881) which uses JXLayer

Comment: Please note that this is not a "please send me the code" site. You may want to show what you accomplished so far, how you are going to do the rotation and what problems you ran into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just don't know how to **start**, here is a hint:

- implement a MouseMotionListener to track the MousePosition
- to rotate components you can override their `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method and rotate with `((Graphics2D)g).rotate(degreeInRadians)`. Keep in mind that this probably crops your components.