# rotate a JPanel to display it upside down when launched?

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I have a JFrame with a JPanel in it, the component i have added to the JPanel needs needs to be displayed upside down (its a JFreeChart) is there a simple way to rotate it by 180 degrees?

```
package testchart;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYAreaRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

public class test99 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    XYSeries series1= new XYSeries("AAA needle");
    series1.add(0.0,16);
    series1.add(-1.168,15);
    series1.add(1.168,15);
    series1.add(-1.219,14);
    series1.add(1.219,14);
    series1.add(-1.270,13);
    series1.add(1.270,13);
    series1.add(-1.321,12);
    series1.add(1.321,12);
    series1.add(-1.372,11);
    series1.add(1.372,11);
    series1.add(-1.422,10);
    series1.add(1.422,10);
    series1.add(-1.473,9);
    series1.add(1.473,9);
    series1.add(-1.524,8);
    series1.add(1.524,8);
    series1.add(-1.600,7);
    series1.add(1.600,7);
    series1.add(-1.712,6);
    series1.add(1.712,6);
    series1.add(-1.829,5);
    series1.add(1.829,5);
    series1.add(-1.918,4);
    series1.add(1.918,4);
    series1.add(-1.994,3);
    series1.add(1.994,3);
    series1.add(-2.068,2);
    series1.add(2.068,2);
    series1.add(-2.159,1);
    series1.add(2.159,1);
    series1.add(-2.261,0);
    series1.add(2.261,0);


    XYSeriesCollection xyDataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
    xyDataset.addSeries(series1);
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("","","",xyDataset,PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,true,false,false);                
    chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.yellow); 
    XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();  
    //NumberAxis xAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();                             
    //xAxis.setTickLabelsVisible(true);
    //xAxis.setVisible(false);
    //NumberAxis yAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
    //yAxis.setTickLabelsVisible(false);
    //yAxis.setVisible(false);
    XYAreaRenderer renderer = new XYAreaRenderer(); 
    plot.setRenderer(0, renderer);
    plot.setBackgroundPaint       (Color.WHITE);
    JFrame testframe = new JFrame("test chart"); // frame to hold panel
    ChartPanel frame = new ChartPanel(chart);  // chart panel that has the chart and needs to be upside down
    testframe.add(frame); // adds chart to frame 
    testframe.setSize   (200, 600); // frame size
    testframe.setVisible(true);

}  
}
```

thank you for any help given

Comment: There might be away to do this within JFreeChart, but incase there isn't, you can use `JXLayer` to rotate components, which will perform the required translations, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324460/rotating-a-jtextfield-vertically/14328881#14328881)

Answer (score 3):

Try overriding the paintComponent method of JPanel, like so:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class UpsideDownJPanel extends JPanel {

    public UpsideDownJPanel() {}

    public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
            Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) graphics;
            int x = this.getWidth() / 2;
            int y = this.getHeight() / 2;
            g.rotate(Math.toRadians(180.0), x, y);
            super.paintComponent(g);
    }

}
```

If my logic is correct this should flip everything inside the JPanel 180 degrees.

Comment: I am really sorry i am unsure how to add this to my code, i have edited my original post to show the full test code, could you please help?

Comment: The problem with this is that it won't translate user interactions, like mouse movements and clicks...

Comment: this jpanel will not need to be clicked on or anything, it simply is the view that needs to be upside down so interactions really donot matter for this panel.

Answer (score 2):

As shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsFHw.png), rotating the view causes the range axis and legend to be inverted, too. As an alternative, you can invert the dataset, as shown below:

```
Inverted series = new Inverted("AAA needle");
series.add(…);
…
series.invert();
…
private static class Inverted extends XYSeries {

    List<XYDataItem> list = data;

    public Inverted(Comparable key) {
        super(key);
    }

    public void invert() {
        double max = getMaxY();
        for (XYDataItem item : list) {
            item.setY(max - item.getYValue());
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

SSCCE, as run:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYAreaRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataItem;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

public class test99 {

    private static class Inverted extends XYSeries {

        List<XYDataItem> list = data;

        public Inverted(Comparable key) {
            super(key);
        }

        public void invert() {
            double max = getMaxY();
            for (XYDataItem item : list) {
                item.setY(max - item.getYValue());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Inverted series = new Inverted("AAA needle");
        series.add(0.0, 16);
        series.add(-1.168, 15);
        series.add(1.168, 15);
        series.add(-1.219, 14);
        series.add(1.219, 14);
        series.add(-1.270, 13);
        series.add(1.270, 13);
        series.add(-1.321, 12);
        series.add(1.321, 12);
        series.add(-1.372, 11);
        series.add(1.372, 11);
        series.add(-1.422, 10);
        series.add(1.422, 10);
        series.add(-1.473, 9);
        series.add(1.473, 9);
        series.add(-1.524, 8);
        series.add(1.524, 8);
        series.add(-1.600, 7);
        series.add(1.600, 7);
        series.add(-1.712, 6);
        series.add(1.712, 6);
        series.add(-1.829, 5);
        series.add(1.829, 5);
        series.add(-1.918, 4);
        series.add(1.918, 4);
        series.add(-1.994, 3);
        series.add(1.994, 3);
        series.add(-2.068, 2);
        series.add(2.068, 2);
        series.add(-2.159, 1);
        series.add(2.159, 1);
        series.add(-2.261, 0);
        series.add(2.261, 0);
        series.invert();

        XYSeriesCollection xyDataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
        xyDataset.addSeries(series);
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("", "", "",
            xyDataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, false, false);
        chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.yellow);
        XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
        XYAreaRenderer renderer = new XYAreaRenderer();
        plot.setRenderer(0, renderer);
        plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
        JFrame testframe = new JFrame("test chart");
        testframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ChartPanel frame = new ChartPanel(chart){

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(200, 600);
            }
        };
        testframe.add(frame);
        testframe.pack();
        testframe.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: I originally did it that way, not as elegant as yours though, however, i need the needle part to be rendered, is there a way to render above the line and not below the line if this is the case?

Comment: You might tinker with the background and series paints; I'd modify the renderer only as a last resort.