# Java rotating non-square JPanel component

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, rotation, awt

I am attempting to rotate a GridLayout filled with text labels to simulate a portrait orientation view due to an OS restriction. The JPanel they are inside of is not square, so when rotating 90 degrees the labels cut off based on dimensions of the JPanel. Is it possible to resize the layout based on the rotation to still fit within the JPanel? Researching into this showed many options for rotations, but only for square JPanels.

To further explain my problem: when I rotate the labels painted inside they stay formatted to the normal oriented x,y, and I want it to format the layout to fit into the 90 degree rotated x,y (so basically y and x are flipped). currently a portion of my grid is cut off after rotating. Also the final display should fit all 13 by 24 letters filled in the current JPnel.

edit: Using vague comments shows I need to paint after rotating, but doing so crops the grid and does not fill back to my preferred size.

JPanel code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Screen extends JPanel {

   private JLabel[][] labels = new JLabel[13][24];
   private GridLayout layout;

   public Screen() {

      //setLocation(315,35);
      layout = new GridLayout(13, 24);
      layout.preferredLayoutSize(this);
      //setBounds(315, 65, 243, 350);
      setBounds(315, 65, 243, 350);
      setLayout(layout);

      for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < 24; j++) {
            labels[i][j] = new JLabel();
            labels[i][j].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            add(labels[i][j]);
         }
      }

      //testing new letter
      for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < 24; j++) {
            labels[i][j].setText("T");
            labels[i][j].setForeground(Color.GREEN);
         }
      }

      setBackground(Color.black);
      setVisible(true);
      repaint();
   }

   @Override
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      //Rotates screen graphics to correct orientation
      Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
      int w2 = getWidth() / 2;
      int h2 = getHeight() / 2;
      g2d.rotate(Math.PI / 2, w2, h2);

      super.paintComponent(g);
      setSize(243,350);

   }
}
```

test code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;

public class RotateTest {

   public static class Frame extends JFrame {

      public Frame() {
         Screen screen = new Screen();

         JLayeredPane pane = new JLayeredPane();
         setUndecorated(false);
         setSize(800, 480);

         setVisible(true);
         setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         pane.add(screen, 0, 0);
         pane.setVisible(true);
         add(pane);
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Frame frame = new Frame();
   }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by rotate, have the labels that were in a row now be in a column? Where is your current rotating code?

Comment: Look at the paint component @Override method.  He/She is doing something similar to rotating the entire screen, except for it's just a single component (GridLayout)

Comment: This will come back haunt you ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, is there a better method of doing this is what you mean?

Comment: First, take a look at this [rotating components example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324460/rotating-a-jtextfield-vertically/14328881#14328881)

Comment: Rotating a Graphics context in this manner does not translate events associated with the container or it's components

Comment: I'm not sure I was clear on my question then, because I am aware events do not rotate with, when I rotate the labels painted inside they stay formatted to the normal oriented x,y, and I want it to format the layout to fit into the 90 degree rotated x,y (so basically y and x are flipped). currently a portion of my grid is cut off after rotating.

Comment: I understand the question, there's just a better way to achieve it ;)

Comment: So what's the better way? You don't have many options to rotate the GridLayout and you can't resize it to an aspect ratio...

Comment: Also take a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156518/rotate-an-image-in-java) for calculating the resulting image size

Comment: Take a look at the previous example I linked

Comment: You do understand that an image and a GridLayout component are completely two different animals right?  The entire premise of this problem is that you can't easily resize the GridLayout component after rotating it.

Comment: I think you fail to understand how they are related. The size of the paintable area will be determined by the preferred size of the component to be painted, which is determined by the layout manager, they are linked...

Comment: Are you simply saying that the preferred size of the content of each cell in the GridLayout will determine the overall size of the GridLayout?

Comment: Referring to where you linked other questions, moving where the paintcomponent is only causing the opposite effect, cuts off sides instead of the top, nowhere does it quite say how the resizing can be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The process of rotating a component is more complicated then just painting the rotated image.  There are a number of interconnected layers which generate contractual obligations.

For example, the size of the clipping rectangle set to the `Graphics` context that is passed to your component for painting is determined by the current size of the component, this size is calculated by the layout manager, but may consider the preferred size of the individual component...

That's a lot of re-wiring that needs to be considered...call my lazy, but if I can find a ready made solution, I'd prefer to use it, so based on [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324460/rotating-a-jtextfield-vertically/14328881#14328881), I can generate the following...

[image: Rotate]

The red `LineBorder` around the field panel is there to show that the entire component is been rotated, not just it's children.  The use of `pack` also demonstrates that this solution is still honouring it's contractual obligations to the rest of the API

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import org.jdesktop.jxlayer.JXLayer;
import org.pbjar.jxlayer.demo.TransformUtils;
import org.pbjar.jxlayer.plaf.ext.transform.DefaultTransformModel;

public class RotateExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new RotateExample();
    }

    public RotateExample() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new ExamplePane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ExamplePane extends JPanel {

        private FieldPane fieldPane;
        private DefaultTransformModel transformModel;

        private JButton rotate;
        private double angle;

        public ExamplePane() {

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            rotate = new JButton("Rotate");
            rotate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    transformModel.setRotation(Math.toRadians((angle += 90)));
                    SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(ExamplePane.this).pack();
                }
            });


            fieldPane = new FieldPane();

            transformModel = new DefaultTransformModel();
            transformModel.setRotation(Math.toRadians(0));
            transformModel.setScaleToPreferredSize(true);
            JXLayer<JComponent> rotatePane = TransformUtils.createTransformJXLayer(fieldPane, transformModel);

            JPanel content = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            content.add(rotatePane);

            add(rotate, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            add(content);

        }
    }

    public class FieldPane extends JPanel {

        public FieldPane() {
            setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
            field.setText("Hello world");

            add(field);

        }
    }
}
```

**Caveats**

This requires [JXLayer](http://java.net/projects/jxlayer/) (I was using version 3), [SwingX](http://swingx.java.net/) (I was using version 1.6.4) and Piet Blok's excellent examples, which no longer seem to be available on the net...

I've put all the source code of JXLayer (version 3) and Piet's examples into a single [zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/re1hmvypp19oqy1/JXLayer-PBJar-Demo.zip) and I would suggest, if you are interested, you grab a copy and store it some where safe.

You will also need [JHLabs filters](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/index.html)

**Updated**

And using your `Screen` panel (without the custom painting)...

[image: Rotate]