# Rotating a JButton in java swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, jbutton

I was wondering how one could go about rotating a JButton in Java?
I don't have any code to show for it but wanted to know if there are any built-in or imported methods I could use to rotate a JButton.

I am new to this environment, so pardon me if I get the format of a question wrong.
Thank you!

Comment: There's no "simple" way to achieve this, but you could try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25252127/java-rotating-non-square-jpanel-component/25253453#25253453) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22976226/is-there-any-way-i-can-rotate-this-90-degrees/22976755#22976755) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50310352/updating-a-rotated-jlabel-using-graphics2d-causes-old-and-new-text-to-merge-toge/50311131#50311131)

Comment: Check out the [Rotated Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/rotated-icon/) and [Text Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/04/02/text-icon/). It shows how you  can create a TextIcon, rotate the Icon and then add the Icon to the JButton to give the effect of a rotated button.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.