# How to rotate a JButton?

Tags: java, rotation, jbutton

Is it possible to rotate a JButton? In other words, I want to change the JButton's angle, for example to 45°. Is there a particular method for this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324460/rotating-a-jtextfield-vertically

Answer (score -1):

As i know you can get absolution position of button with layouts.You can set any position of your elemnt in frame.AS i know it's impossible to rotate a button. You can implements Component and try to create your , and try to draw as you want. But i think rotating button is absolutely unreal.

Comment: As [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324460/rotating-a-jtextfield-vertically) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22976226/is-there-any-way-i-can-rotate-this-90-degrees/22976755#22976755) it is very possible and in fact very easy, but I wouldn't use custom painting as this won't translate the mouse events