# Rotate text present on JLabel without rotating border

Tags: java, swing

I want to rotate the text present on my `JComponent` to vertical, `JComponent` also contains border painted in `paintComponent` method, I don't want to rotate that border, only text.

I already used `graphics2D` `rotate` function, but it rotate component border as well, which fails when my component is rectangle.

Please suggest me any approch to rotate only text.
This is currently my JComponent :

[image]

And what I want :

[image]

Actually it's not duplicate. I already used below code:

```
  Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2.rotate(Math.PI / 4, bi.getWidth() / 2, bi.getHeight() / 2);
```

but problem is that, it also rotate border, I don't want that.

All the solutions given are not working, it rotate the border as well. I don't want to rotate the border, only text.
This is what I get after rotate with some angle:
[image]

Comment: instead of coding , you can easily rotate your photo then use it in your code

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi, actually it's text, not photo, that is my JComponent with white border, in which I am drawing different text

Comment: Hi @kevto, actually I already referred that example, but it's not what I need. Is there some approch, where I can rotate only certain part of the JComponent?

Comment: i think here is what you want :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324460/rotating-a-jtextfield-vertically

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi : Hi thanks for the comment, but link you provided is also not working for me. approch given in that also rotate border of my jcomponent.

Comment: In your code you talk about rotating text. But in the code you post you are drawing an image. That doesn't make sense. Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates what your are doing. Only once  a proper `SSCCE` is posted will I vote to reopen the question.

Comment: Did you tried to give a JPanel your static border and adding your JLabel / image on this Panel ? You could rotate the text the same way without moving the border I suppose ?

Answer (score -1):

Remember that the `Graphics` object has a lot of state in it. This includes the current transformation. Your current code modifies the state and does not restore it to the original situation.

After drawing your image, you should "undo" the rotation. This can be done either by rotating in the other the direction or by creating a new graphics object (`g2.create()`) specifically to draw the rotated content. If you do the latter, make sure to `dispose()` the temporary graphics object you created.