# How to create vertical tabs in Java?

Tags: java, swing, tabs, vertical-alignment, jtabbedpane

I would like to get the effect like if JTabbedPane would be turned 90 degrees counterclockwise (only tabs but not the content inside tabs). What is the best way to implement that in Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this solution:

http://oreilly.com/pub/a/mac/2002/03/22/vertical_text.html

The text was painted vertically and tried as an icon on the tab.  This way you don't have to modify JTabbedPane you just use a custom Icon in the tab.

Of course you would also have to specify the tab placement to be on the Left.

Comment: and some examples for that http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/TabbedPane.htm + 1

Comment: @mKorbel: I didn't find vertical tabs examples there.

Comment: @bancer really time convert your requirements to code that you show here, maybe is about small hack, you can Edit your original question, then we'd look at it

Comment: The link provided by jzd is good. The solution and implementation provided there is not ideal but is good and acceptable.

Comment: The link is dead, an archived version can be viewed here: https://web.archive.org/web/20160727035553/http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/mac/2002/03/22/vertical_text.html

Answer (score 5):

You can specify the placement in the constructor:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#JTabbedPane%28int%29

or in the setter:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#setTabPlacement%28int%29

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative, consider [`JToolBar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JToolBar.html) with `orientation` set to `VERTICAL` in a `BorderLayout`, `EAST` or `WEST`. It's fairly easy [rotate text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238037/how-do-i-align-this-text-correctly/6238908#6238908) in the button's `Icon`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try `setTabPlacement(SwingConstants.LEFT)` or [this component](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/component.htm)

Comment: I don't see how that link helps.  Plus the tab placement would not create vertical text.

Comment: As I understood, author needs vertical tabs but horizontal text, I decided it from this @(only tabs but not the content inside tabs)@

Answer (score 0):

You could try and extend the tabpane class, in the overloaded paint method, get the graphics object, say `g2d` is the argument of the overloaded paint method:

```
super(g2d.rotate(Pi/2));
```

as a starter