# How to create loading animation from a transparent GIF in Java

Tags: java, animation, gif, splash-screen

I have a loading sign gif - animated and transparent background.
How can I use it in Java - show it's animation and make its background transparent?

I use this code to load it as [splashscreen](http://www2.eng.cam.ac.uk/~tpl/asp/source/SplashWindow.java)

I'm creating gif transparent animation with [ajaxload](http://ajaxload.info/)

Comment: What have you done till now, any [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783535/java-swing-loading-animation)

Comment: I didn't manage to do anything, so i deleted my code. In general - I tried to load if on a Jlabel - animation was shown, but the background wasn't transparent. When using opacity on the jpanel - everything becomes transparent. So - no luck :-(

Comment: I think this will solve your problems http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/

Comment: I updated my question. Jonathan.cruz - I tried this and didn't helped me. probably it's the rendering of the gif or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean, perhaps something like...

[image: Super]

The easiest way is to start with a `ImageIcon` and a `JLabel`

```
ImageIcon animatedGif = new ImageIcon(...); // Path/URL to your gif
JLabel splashLabel = new JLabel(animatedGif);

// Add to your splash screen...
```

Once you have the basic set up, you will probably want to undecorated the frame (or just use a JWindow)

```
myJFrame.setUndecorated(true);
```

Oh, of course, if you want something really over the top, you use a transparent window...

[image: Over the top]

Comment: I tried you solution (JFrame and JWindow) and again - i see the animated gif as expected, BUT - it's not transparent - it as a light grey non-transparent background :-(  Any other ideas?

Comment: There's a few little tricks, first, make sure the actual container is transparent (this includes the content pane of the window). Have a read through [How to Create Translucent and Shaped Windows](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/)

Comment: AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(myJFrame, false) did the trick! thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [MadProgramer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer/)
Here is a working code:

```
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("images/ajax-loader.gif");
    JLabel label=new JLabel(icon);
    JWindow myJFrame=new JWindow();
    myJFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    myJFrame.add(label,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    myJFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    myJFrame.setOpacity(0.5f);
    myJFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    label.setOpaque(false);
    AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(myJFrame, false);
    myJFrame.pack();
    myJFrame.setVisible(true);
```